# Getting table rows count by using count 1

Tags: kdb, k

To get an appropriate table rows count I thought to use a naive approach: use `count 1` construct. And it works in a simple case:

```
q)t:([]sym:`a`a`b`b);
q)select cnt: count 1 by sym from t
sym| cnt
---| ---
a  | 2
b  | 2
```

But when I added other fields, I've got wrong result:

```
q)select cnt: count 1, sym by sym from t
sym| cnt sym
---| -------
a  | 1   a a
b  | 1   b b
```

Why does `count 1` work (or just it seems so) in one column case and failed with multiple columns?

---

**Upd:** Expected to get something like this

```
sym| cnt sym
---| -------
a  | 2   a a
b  | 2   b b
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output from this query? Also, is it `count i` you're trying to use or `count l`?

Comment: `count 1` - like in Oracle, though in Oracle this simply references to the first column.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `count 1` will produce the result you're looking for, nor even a consistent one.

I think you might want to use `count i` instead. When selecting `by sym` you are specifying which column you want to count by.

```
q)t:([]sym:`a`a`b`b)
q)select cnt:count i,sym by sym from t
sym| cnt sym
---| -------
a  | 2   a a
b  | 2   b b
q).z.K
3.6
```

A point to note however is that this solution will not work on kdb+ 4.0.

```
q)t:([]sym:`a`a`b`b)
q)select cnt:count i,sym by sym from t
'dup names for cols/groups sym
  [0]  select cnt:count i,sym by sym from t
                                    ^
q).z.K
4f
```